# Logo não é posicionada corretamente no celular

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Estou desenvolvendo um site e me deparei com um erro no qual a logo não é exibida corretamente quando o site é aberto no celular, mesmo no Responsive Design Mode do Firefox ela é exibida do modo que eu desejo, porém ao abrir no telefone aparece de outro modo, ao invez da logo "escorrer" para a esquerda do meu menu de navegação e ficar no topo da página, ela fica abaixo do menu de navegação.

Segue o link para que possam observar o html: 
http://primerproducoes.com/primernew/site/

Como fica no celular:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6twHm.jpg

O resultado desejado seria esse:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM7QN.png

Já tentei alterar a width do objeto que seria o mais óbvio a se fazer porém não muda em nada.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Eu fiz um teste definindo max-width e parece ter funcionado da forma que vocÊ gostaria.

```
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll;" href="#page-top" style="max-width: 260px;">
    <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Primer Produções HD Logo" id="logo">
</a>
```

Como você quer alterar apenas a forma como aparece no mobile, você pode adicionar essas linhas ao seu CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        max-width:260px;
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Resolveu o problema, mas o seu post diz _@media (min-width: 576px)_ quando o que funcionou foi _max-width_. Obrigado pela resposta rápida :)

Comment: Falta de atenção minha, mas bom saber que ajudou.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que vc não seguiu direito a documentação do Navbar do Bootstrap, agora acredito que só vai conseguir arrumar isso no jeitinho...

Veja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dica é remover o float quando a tela for menor que `992px` usando um `media querie`

```
@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        float: inherit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade esse Boostrap veio com o template que eu usei, estou tendo vários problemas com ele, tenho que ler a documentação novamente com mais atenção. Obrigado pela resposta rápida :)

Comment: @RonaldoGueller aqui tem a documentação da Navbar da versão 3 que me parece ser a que vc está usando https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar . Outra coisa é que infelizmente vc só pode dar a resposta como aceita ✔ para apenas uma resposta... Mas se vc achar que ajudou vc tb pode usar as setinhas para sinalizar. Boa sorte no projeto